# $.get return json_encoded php array to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to load a php array from a php file into a javascript array in a javascript file.

Originally, I was just doing `var wordsArray = <?php echo json_encode($wordsArray) ?>;` in a php file to get it, but now I've put all Javascript functions a `.js` file, which can't run PHP. Is there a `$.get` function that can return a php array?

something like:

**JavaScript: Utilities.js file**

```
$.get("php/Quests.php", {},
    function(returned_data) {
        var wordsArray = returned_data;
    }
);
```

**PHP: Quests.php file**

```
<?php       
    include 'DbConnect.php';
    $sql = $mysqli->query(
     "SELECT t.*, v.* 
     FROM task t 
     INNER JOIN vocabtask vt ON (t.id = vt.taskid)
     INNER JOIN vocab v ON (v.id = vt.vocabid)
     WHERE vt.taskid = 1");
    $wordsArray = array();               
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $wordsArray[$row['chinese']] = $row['english'];
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);  

   //return php array as json_encoded to js file through get function
    echo json_encode($wordsArray);  

?>
```

---

EDIT:

Or instead of the $.get, I tried doing this on the PHP file:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var wordsArray =json_encode($wordsArray); </script>";
```

Then in JS do:

```
alert(wordsArray[1]);
```

Would something like this work?

Comment: Can't you just echo out the json in a js var when the page loads and have the external js use it as any other local var?

Comment: @ZombieBunnies can you give an example?

Comment: Have you actually tried the code you've written here?

Comment: @winterblood yes, why do you ask? please see edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this.

echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var wordsArray = " . json_encode($wordsArray) . ";
    //this will output the contents of wordsArray into the console
     console.dir(wordsArray);

     // check the console. f12 or ctrl+shift+k
 </script>";
```

Comment: in the JS file... `alert(wordsArray[1]);` outputs `undefined`

Comment: `console.dir(wordsArray);` what do you see in your console? or view the source to see what's being returned by `json_encode( $wordsArray)`

Comment: in my js file, I put `console.dir(wordsArray);` which shows `object`.

Comment: yep. inside the console window - f12 in chrome, ctrl+shift+k in firefox

Comment: Right, the console.dir output is `Object`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45421/discussion-between-growler-and-adams)

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP returns a JSON-encoded data, you can parse it in your Javascript using `JSON.parse`:

```
function(returned_data) {
  returned_data = JSON.parse(returned_data);
}
```

`returned_data` will now be a JSON object instead of the original string.